# Combining Scalaz IO monad with Stream for simple echo program using takeWhile method

Tags: io, monads, scalaz, io-monad

I'm looking for a solution for "Life, the Universe, and Everything" problem on spoj.com using Scalaz IO Monad and Stream.
The problem is to rewrite small numbers from input to output and to stop processing input after reading in the number 42.
I created following classes:

```
import scalaz._, effect._

def ReadInt: IO[Int] = IO {
    readInt
}
def PrintInt(i: Int): IO[Unit] = IO {
    println(i)
}
def EchoInt: IO[Int] = {
    for {
        i <- ReadInt
        _ <- PrintInt(i)
    } yield (i)
}
```

Never-ending loop works as expected:

```
scala> import Scalaz._
scala> Stream.continually(EchoInt).sequence.unsafePerformIO
12
22
32
42
52
```

However, when I want it to finish on the number 42 it doesn't finish as well:

```
scala> Stream.continually(EchoInt).sequence.map(_.takeWhile(_ != 42)).unsafePerformIO
12
22
32
42
52
```

I know that this code is supposed to print 42 after all (as opposed to problem statement), but I wanted to simplify the example code.

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: My build.sbt file: scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq{ "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.4" "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-effect" % "7.1.4" }

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.continually(EchoInt).sequence` repeats `EchoInt` infinite times, so your program is basically an infinite loop.

What you want to do is to put some sort of `break` into your loop, which will analyze the input on each iteration and stop the loop if the input equals 42. There is no `break` in functional programming (because there are no loops, only recursion), so you simply do not continue the recursion:

```
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

...

def echoInts: IO[Unit] = {
  for {
    i <- EchoInt
    _ <- echoInts.whenM(i != 42) // Break if i == 42
  } yield ()
}

echoInts.unsafePerformIO()
```